# How to say "Let's have a quick chat"?

Tags: translation

How to say "Let's have a quick chat" in an informal environment, e.g. among colleagues?

The emphasis is on the usage "chat", i.e. it's not "Let's have a discussion", or "Let's have a meeting". It's "Let's have a chat" as the word is used in English.

Comment: To me, "Let's have a quick chat", even in an informal environment, implies "Let's have a quick chat (about something)", which seems like there's something that needs to be resolved. Instead, do you mean something like "let's go have lunch (where we can chat about anything, not necessarily important stuff)"?

Comment: ^ `"Let's have a quick chat (about something)", which seems like there's something that needs to be resolved.` <- もしそういうことだったら。。「ちょっといい？」「ちょっといいですか？」って言いますね・・または「ちょっと話せる？」とかですかね・・

Answer (score 1):

I believe you would say

> 「ちょっと/少しの）お話がありますけど、（いいですか）？

I have seen that in books (not manga) where the character wants to talk briefly with someone and they say that.

If you were trying to say person A wants to chat quickly with person B they could say

> "AさんはBさんにお話しがある"

Hope that helps!

Comment: お話しがある means "I have something to tell you". It doesn't imply light conversation.

Answer (score 1):

When I casually *talk about* chatting with friends, I usually express that thought as:

> 「友達【ともだち】と話【はな】しをする。」
> "(I) talk to (my) friend(s)."

「話」more closely means "talk" rather than "chat", but it does not imply a formal kind of conversation.

So I would express "let's talk" by ending using 「ましょう」. A common construction using this is:

> 「食【た】べましょう！」
> "Let's eat!"
>
> 「話【はな】しましょう！」
> "Let's talk!"

Answer (score 1):

As @Chocolate states in the comment above, native speakers would often **not** even explicitly mention "having a chat" when all we want is a casual chat.

We often say:

・「ちょっといい？」

・「ちょっといい + かな/ですか？」

・「（ほんの）ちょっと時間{じかん}くれる？」

・「（今{いま}）少{すこ}し時間 + くれる/もらえる？」

Each one is uttered with a rising intonation at the end and everyone will understand that you would like a quick chat.